# DVCS - tag multiple revisions

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, merge, dvcs

I have in mind such release workflow:
 - One branch is a `trunk` branch - it may has sub-branches for features and other purposes.
 - Second branch is `stable` - it represents releases for production.
 - Revisions of `trunk` - are tagged for versions of releases. If I want to make a release - I must nominate one or multiple changesets for release version and then merge them into `stable`, and end final revision of this multi-merge will be a new `stable` version.

There is an options - use some external tool for track to which version revisions are belong, or write this information in commit-messages - but I don't like them, because I want to store this information in DVCS, and not depend on any external software for release management.

And so my questions is:
 - Is it good scheme at all?
 - Is there such tool for any popular DVSC, for mass-tagging of revisions?

Comment: "mass-tagging"?  Do you mean you want to tag all revisions that are part of a release?  That's not how Git does tags.  They're meant to tag a single revision that represents all of the history up to that release.  Also, the workflow your describing sounds similar to [this one](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to do in Mercurial where you can have multiple heads for a named branch, but in either git or mercurial, you're probably better off using a branch named something like 'release_candidate' into which you merge any feature branches you consider to be candidates for release.  Then TPTB merge 'release_candidate' into 'stable' or don't, and if they don't you just create a new release candidate with the acceptable subset of the rejected candidate -- you can always create a new branch and merge only what you want into it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good scheme at all?

No. Separate "stable" branch in useless entity with additional headache only (at least in Mercurial and Git), tagging inside "trunk" will work

> Is there such tool for any popular DVCS, for mass-tagging of revisions?

No (at least I don't know such tools). But (for Mercurial, f.e) it isn't needed at all: with some revset's magic you can always get "track to which version /tag in repo/ revisions are belong"

Comment: Disagree about useless `stable` - what if production require to grab some non-sequential not last in history changesets from `trunk` (which represent history of development process)? So I will need to merge them inside `trunk` and make new commit, which is highly possible will be irrelevant for current state of development that already could go away from state represented by the release.

Comment: @GillBates - your requirement to PROD are rather exotic and unrelated to real life, but, anyway - additional **anonymous branch** (in which you rebase|graft changesets)in **development branch** isn't a big problem